# issue with create table inside if/else block

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a table in a MySQL stored procedure depending upon the values of some of the passed parameters.  My code is as follows:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE testifelse(IN CurrentGPA varchar(40), IN CurrentGPAValue varchar(40))
    BEGIN    
        IF CurrentGPAValue IS NULL THEN CREATE TABLE tableCurrentGPA(SELECT DISTINCT u.user_id AS uid FROM users u);
        ELSE CREATE TABLE tableCurrentGPA(SELECT DISTINCT udata.user_id AS uid FROM userdata udata WHERE udata.userDataTypeName = CurrentGPA AND udata.userDataText = CurrentGPAValue);
    END
```

I'm getting an error stating: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5.

I'm not sure what I've done wrong here.  The syntax looks fine to me and the queries seem well-formulated.

Comment: Is that the full error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `END IF` statement.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE testifelse(IN CurrentGPA varchar(40), IN CurrentGPAValue varchar(40))
    BEGIN    
        IF CurrentGPAValue IS NULL THEN CREATE TABLE tableCurrentGPA(SELECT DISTINCT u.user_id AS uid FROM users u);
        ELSE CREATE TABLE tableCurrentGPA(SELECT DISTINCT udata.user_id AS uid FROM userdata udata WHERE udata.userDataTypeName = CurrentGPA AND udata.userDataText = CurrentGPAValue);
        END IF;
    END
```

Comment: I just figured this out in the other tab after a good hour of head-scratching.  Funny how that works :P

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Haha, yes. Mysql error reports aren't very intuitive. You're welcome!